# std::move вне пространства имен std

Tags: c++, c++11

Почему этот код работает, если даже если мы не используем пространство имен std?

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "test";
    std::cout << move(s); // <= move без std::, никакого using namespace std нет
}
```

Однако `move(1)` не скомпилируется, тк нет функции move, а `std::move(1)` - да.

Проверено в g++6.3 -std=c++14, clang++5.0 и 6.0 -stdc++1z

Comment: Скорее всего алиас функции или макрос

Comment: @LLENN Тогда почему не работает `move(1)`? `std::move(1)` отлично работает, при `move(1)` ошибка, именно в том, что нет функции move, а не в неподходящем типе аргумента

Comment: Алиас может быть расположен внутри `<string>` или `<iostream>`. Загляните, возможно поймете почему. А возможно происходит неявный вызов `s.move()`;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Это так называемый `Argument-Dependent Lookup (ADL)`.
Если кратко, то к функциям-кандидатам при поиске подходящей функции также добавляются функции из пространств имен фактических аргументов.

Рассмотрим простой пример (в конце имеется полный код):

```
namespace First
{
    struct Type {};
    
    void foo(Type)
    {
        std::cout << "First foo" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void bar(First::Type, First::Type)
    {
        std::cout << "First::bar" << std::endl;
    }
    
}


namespace Second
{
    struct Type {};
    
    void foo(Type)
    {
        std::cout << "Second foo" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void bar(First::Type, Second::Type)
    {
        std::cout << "Second::bar" << std::endl;
    }
    
}


int main()
{
    First::Type f;
    Second::Type s;

    //Аргумент из пространства имен First, 
    //поэтому поиск будем производить и в пространстве имен First
    foo(f);

    //Аргумент из пространства имен Second, 
    //поэтому поиск будем производить и в пространстве имен Second
    foo(s);

    //Один аргумент из пространства имен First, другой - из Second. 
    //Поэтому поиск будет производиться и в First и в Second. 
    //Но для вызова подходит только функция Second::bar
    bar(f, s);
}
```

Рассмотрим более практический случай, когда `ADL` помогает делу. Возьмем простой шаблон функции, которая во время работы где-то в своих недрах обменивает значения двух своих аргументов:

```
template<typename T>
void zoo(T & one, T & two)
{
    std::swap(one, two);
}
```

`zoo` использует `std::swap` для обмена значений.

Представим, что два объекта типа `First::Type` можно обменять местами эффективнее, чем это делает `std::swap`. Нам необходимо, чтобы для типа `First::Type` эта функция использовала более эффективный обмен.
Для начала необходимо добавить функцию `swap` в пространство имен `First`:

```
namespace First
{
    //...    
    void swap(Type &, Type &)
    {
        std::cout << "First::swap" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Теперь необходимо как-то заставить `zoo` вызывать `First::swap` вместо `std::swap`. В этом нам поможет `ADL`, мы просто убираем пространства имен при использовании `swap`:

```
template<typename T>
void zoo(T & one, T & two)
{
    swap(one, two);
}
```

Теперь `swap` будет искаться в текущем пространстве имен и в пространстве имен своих аргументов. Но здесь возникает новая проблема. Что делать с типами, для которых нет `swap`? А для них мы продолжим использовать `std::swap`, просто добавим `using` в функцию:

```
template<typename T>
void zoo(T & one, T & two)
{
    using std::swap;//Обеспечит вызов std::swap для типов
    swap(one, two);//для которых не предоставлен более подходящий swap
}
```

Теперь, благодаря `ADL` для типов для которых предусмотрен собственный `swap` будет использоваться именно он, а для других - стандартный.

```
//...
zoo(f, f);

int a = 10;
int b = 20;
zoo(a, b);
std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
```

Полный код примера:

```
#include <iostream>



namespace First
{
    struct Type {};
    
    void foo(Type)
    {
        std::cout << "First foo" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void bar(First::Type, First::Type)
    {
        std::cout << "First::bar" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void swap(Type &, Type &)
    {
        std::cout << "First::swap" << std::endl;
    }
}


namespace Second
{
    struct Type 
    {};
    
    void foo(Type)
    {
        std::cout << "Second foo" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void bar(First::Type, Second::Type)
    {
        std::cout << "Second::bar" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void swap(Type &, Type &)
    {
        std::cout << "Second::swap" << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void zoo(T & one, T & two)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(one, two);
}


int main()
{
    First::Type f;
    Second::Type s;

    foo(f);
    foo(s);
    bar(f, s);
    
    zoo(f, f);
    zoo(s, s);
    
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    zoo(a, b);
    std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
}
```

http://rextester.com/LWCQY38186

Answer (score 6):

Как я понимаю, работает ADL (Argument-Dependent Lookup), выполняющий поиск в соответствующем `string` пространстве имен.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Если не так - пусть гуру подправят...